# View when someone is busy without having full calendar access

Tags: vba, outlook, calendar

I've written the following to get calendar items for a certain date range:

```vb
Sub printCal()

    Dim sesh As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set sesh = ThisOutlookSession.Session
    
    Dim myCal As MAPIFolder
    Set myCal = sesh.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)

    Dim target As Recipient
    With sesh.GetSelectNamesDialog
        .AllowMultipleSelection = False 'aside: this doesn't seem to force me to select only one
        .ForceResolution = True
        Debug.Print "displaying: "; .Display
        Set target = .Recipients.Item(1)
    End With
    
    Dim targetCalendar As MAPIFolder
    Set targetCalendar = sesh.GetSharedDefaultFolder(target, olFolderCalendar)
    
    Dim x As Variant
    'ISSUE these calendars aren't VBA accessible unless shared all details
    'https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bffddb8e-0344-459f-a586-105035eb4192/permission-levels-for-shared-calendars-when-reading-with-vba?forum=outlookdev
    For Each x In targetCalendar.Items.Restrict( _
        "[Start]>='08/06/2022 1 AM' and [End] <='08/06/2022 10 PM'" _
        )
        Debug.Print x.Start; x.Duration; "mins", x.Subject
    Next
End Sub
```

This works for my calendar or someone who has shared their calendar publicly/with me specifically. It does not work for a calendar I can see in the scheduling assistant (they are in my organisation) but the titles of meetings are hidden.

I'm trying to write a VBA addin for Outlook that uses an algorithm I came up with to schedule meetings.

I only need to know when people are busy. Can I get it from the raw mail server rather than the Outlook API?

Comment: Have you checked the link mentioned in the code  - [Permission levels for shared calendars when reading with VBA](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bffddb8e-0344-459f-a586-105035eb4192/permission-levels-for-shared-calendars-when-reading-with-vba?forum=outlookdev) ?

Comment: No, `targetCalendar.Items` is just an empty object with no data which errors when you try to access the data, e.g. `targetCalendar.Items.Count` raises an error `-2147221233 The operation failed.` _(Which for reference is [`_MAPI_E_NOT_FOUND`](https://www.magnumdb.com/search?q=-2147221233)_

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev Yes sorry I wrote the code and found+read the link. That's the issue, this method requires "all sharing permissions" and I am not going to get those permissions. Using the Scheduling Assistant _manually_ does not require the full permission, it just hides the meeting titles and details but shows the calendar as free/busy. So given I only want the same detail as I can obtain manually, I'm hoping there is a workaround to do it automatically.

Comment: There is no workaround using the Outlook object model. You need to change the permission level. You may try using the Graph SDK, but I am not sure whether it can help or not.

Comment: So you don't think it's possible by bringing up the scheduling assistant using VBA and reading the information from it somehow. I'm not familiar with the outlook object model. E.g. `Inspector.SetSchedulingStartTime` but the inspector class sounds too generic to let you read anything useful about clashes from vba

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev there is actually a good workaround (see answer)

Comment: I don't see where you read properties like `Subject`, `Duration` and etc. like shown in your code above?

Answer (score 0):

`Recipient.FreeBusy` does the trick. It shows when someone is marked as busy for the next 30 days in `n` minute intervals. e.g.

```
Sub useFreeBusy()
    Dim target As Recipient
    Set target = ThisOutlookSession.Session.CreateRecipient("Joe Bloggs")
    
    Dim status As String
    Const INTERVAL As Long = 60
    status = target.FreeBusy(Date, INTERVAL, True)      '60 min intervals 00:00 today, True showing all status info
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Len(status)
        Dim slotTimestamp As Date 
        slotTimestamp = DateAdd("n", INTERVAL * (i - 1), Date)

        Dim statusNumber As String
        statusNumber = Mid(status, i, 1)

        Debug.Print slotTimestamp ;statusNumber  ; "-"; IIf(statusNumber = "0", "Free", "Busy")
    Next i
End Sub
```

Which outputs something like:

```
14/02/2023 08:00:00 0-Free
14/02/2023 09:00:00 0-Free
14/02/2023 10:00:00 0-Free
14/02/2023 11:00:00 0-Free
14/02/2023 12:00:00 2-Busy
14/02/2023 13:00:00 0-Free
14/02/2023 14:00:00 1-Busy
14/02/2023 15:00:00 0-Free
14/02/2023 16:00:00 0-Free
14/02/2023 17:00:00 0-Free
14/02/2023 18:00:00 0-Free
14/02/2023 19:00:00 0-Free
14/02/2023 20:00:00 0-Free
[etc...]
```

Graph SDK requires you to have Global Admin permissions in Azure in order to view the calendars of other users. I don't have this.

Comment: So, you were looking only free/busy information of a particular user without appointment data like shown in your original code?